# VBA - Filter multiple data from range and copy to multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

hoping someone can help because i'm kinda stuck!

I have a some backing data which i am trying to filter by names from a range and then copy each filtered instance of the  data to other sheets which are named the same as the range - if that makes sense???

This is what I've mashed together so far, It does filter the data by range and loops through fine but i'm stuck on how to copy the data to the sheets for each name in the xRg!

```
Set WIP = Worksheets("WIP")
Set Info = Worksheets("Information")

Dim xRg As Excel.Range

For Each xRg In Info.Range("D2:D16")

With WIP
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    
        With Range("X1")
        .AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:=xRg
        End With
        
        With WIP.UsedRange
        .Copy
        End With
                        
    End With

Next xRg
```

Any ideas much appreciated

Comment: Each worksheet could be referenced by `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(xRg.Value)`.

Comment: That's done the trick!

`With WIP.UsedRange

        .Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(xRg.Value).Range("A1")
        
End With`

Thanks for the quick reply!